# Problem installing package libevdev-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to install a package called libevdev-dev for use of cmake in order to use a program called joycond (In order to use my switch joy cons on my computer for use with cemu to play Zelda: Breath of the Wild blah blah blah), but I can't because it requires an older version of a package already installed on my computer (libevdev2) that I can't uninstall without removing half of KDE.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libevdev-dev : Depends: libevdev2 (= 1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2) but 1.11.0+dfsg-1build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to uninstall libevdev2 in order for apt to re-install the older version of it I get a massive list of items to remove, which include but are not limited to my window manager (kwin), my current plasma theme (breeze), and several of the apps I use like cheese, multimc (A minecraft launcher of all things), kdenlive, and more.
Here's the output of `sudo apt remove libevdev2`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  akonadi-backend-mysql appmenu-gtk-module-common appmenu-gtk3-module apt-config-icons-hidpi apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi bolt breeze-cursor-theme catdoc cheese-common cryfs cups-pk-helper debconf-kde-data
  dvdauthor dvgrab encfs fonts-hack fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-ui-core fonts-noto-unhinted freerdp2-x11 genisoimage geoclue-2.0 geoip-database gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gnome-video-effects gnustep-base-common
  gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common haveged hwdata ieee-data iio-sensor-proxy kactivities-bin kate5-data kde-cli-tools-data kdegames-card-data-kf5 kdegames-mahjongg-data-kf5 kdenlive-data kdeplasma-addons-data kdoctools5 khotkeys-data
  kio-extras-data konversation-data kpackagetool5 krita-data ktexteditor-data ktorrent-data kuserfeedback-doc kwayland-data kwin-data lame libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1 libaio1 libappimage0 libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libappstreamqt2
  libaribb24-0 libavif9 libboost-thread1.74.0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcddb2 libchm1 libclang1-11 libclutter-1.0-common libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libdmtx0b libdolphinvcs5 libdvbpsi10
  libebml5 libeditorconfig0 libegl1-mesa-dev libepoxy-dev libepub0 libfakekey0 libfam0 libfcitx-qt5-data libfdk-aac2 libfreecell-solver0 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libfwupd2 libgav1-0 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoip1 libgit2-1.1
  libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libgmic1 libgnustep-base1.27 libgpgmepp6 libgps28 libgrantlee-templates5 libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgsettings-qt1 libgsl25 libgslcblas0 libhavege2
  libhfstospell11 libhttp-parser2.9 libixml10 libjcat1 libkdsoap1 libkf5activities5 libkf5activitiesstats1 libkf5akonadi-data libkf5akonadicalendar-data libkf5akonadicontact-data libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadimime-data
  libkf5akonadinotes-data libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2 libkf5alarmcalendar-data libkf5archive5 libkf5attica-doc libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth-dev-bin libkf5auth-doc libkf5balooengine5 libkf5bluezqt-data
  libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks-doc libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5calendarutils-data libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs-doc libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion-doc libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data
  libkf5config-dev-bin libkf5config-doc libkf5configcore5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets-doc libkf5contacts-data libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons-dev-bin libkf5coreaddons-doc libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5crash-doc
  libkf5dav-data libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons-doc libkf5declarative-data libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5doctools5 libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel-doc libkf5grantleetheme-data libkf5guiaddons-doc libkf5holidays-data libkf5holidays5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n-doc libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes-doc libkf5identitymanagement-data libkf5imap-data
  libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews-doc libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets-doc libkf5js5 libkf5jsapi5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kdegames-data libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5khtml-data libkf5kio-doc
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data libkf5ldap-data libkf5libkdepim-data libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mbox5 libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifications-doc
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5people-data libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5pimtextedit-data libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5sane-data libkf5service-data libkf5service-doc libkf5solid-doc
  libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5su-data libkf5syndication5abi1 libkf5syntaxhighlighting-data libkf5sysguard-data libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5
  libkf5wallet-data libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5widgetsaddons-doc libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem-doc libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui-doc libkfontinst5 libkimageannotator-common libkolabxml1v5
  libkpimgapi-data libksgrd9 libksysguardsystemstats1 libktorrent-l10n liblirc-client0 libllvm11 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmariadb3 libmarkdown2 libmatroska7 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmd4c0 libmlt-data
  libmovit8 libmtdev1 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libneon27-gnutls libobjc4 libopencolorio1v5 libopengl-dev libopenmpt-modplug1 libpackagekitqt5-1 libphonon4qt5-data libplacebo72 libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpowerdevilui5
  libprotobuf-lite23 libproxy-tools libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqalculate21 libqalculate21-data libqapt3 libqgpgme7 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5keychain1 libqt5networkauth5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5qmlmodels5 libqt5qmlworkerscript5
  libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5xml5 libquazip5-1 libquicktime2 libre2-9 libresid-builder0c2a librtaudio6
  libsasl2-modules-kdexoauth2 libscim8v5 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libskk-common libskk0 libsnapd-qt1 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3
  libspatialaudio0 libspectre1 libspeechd2 libsqlite3-dev libsquashfuse0 libssh2-1 libtinyxml2-8 libupnp13 libva-wayland2 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libvncclient1 libvoikko1 libvulkan-dev libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwinpr2-2 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 libxcb-dpms0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-record0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-res0 libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev
  libxcb-xinput0 libxcb-xv0 libxext-dev libxres1 libyaml-cpp0.6 libzip4 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-common mariadb-server-core-10.5 media-player-info oxygen-icon-theme pavucontrol-qt-l10n phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover-common plasma-workspace-data powerdevil-data pulseaudio-module-gsettings python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.sip python3-sip qdbus-qt5 qdoc-qt5
  qml-module-gsettings1.0 qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-kholidays qml-module-org-kde-kitemmodels qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-qmlmodels qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtqml
  qml-module-qtqml-models2 qt5-style-kvantum-l10n qtattributionsscanner-qt5 qtbase5-dev-tools qtspeech5-speechd-plugin recordmydesktop session-migration signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password signon-ui-service signond skkdic
  smartmontools sonnet-plugins sshfs system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev unar usb-creator-common vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization whoopsie whoopsie-preferences x11proto-xext-dev xsettingsd xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  akonadi-server apport-kde ark baloo-kf5 bluedevil breeze cheese debconf-kde-helper dolphin drkonqi elisa evemu-tools fcitx-frontend-qt5 fcitx-skk fcitx5-module-quickphrase-editor ffmpegthumbs frameworkintegration gstreamer-qapt
  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gwenview kaccounts-integration kaccounts-providers kactivitymanagerd kalarm kamera kate kcalc kde-cli-tools kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-mailtransport kde-config-screenlocker kde-config-sddm
  kde-config-tablet kde-config-updates kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle kde-style-breeze kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kdeconnect kded5 kdegraphics-thumbnailers kdenlive kdepim-runtime kdialog keditbookmarks kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys
  kimageformat-plugins kinfocenter kinit kinit-dev kio kio-audiocd kio-extras kio-ldap kio-sieve kmahjongg kmenuedit kmines konsole konsole-kpart konversation kpackagelauncherqml kpat kpeople-vcard krdc krita krita-gmic kross kscreen
  ksshaskpass ksudoku ksystemlog ksystemstats ktexteditor-katepart ktorrent kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-settings-desktop kup-backup kwalletmanager kwayland-integration kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-dev
  kwin-style-breeze kwin-wayland kwin-wayland-backend-drm kwin-x11 kwrited layer-shell-qt libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolorcorrect5 libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libdebconf-kde1 libevdev2
  libevemu3 libfcitx-qt5-1 libinput-bin libinput10 libk3b7 libk3b7-extracodecs libkaccounts2 libkcolorpicker0 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private8 libkf5akonadiagentbase5 libkf5akonadicalendar5abi2 libkf5akonadicontact5abi1
  libkf5akonadicore5abi2 libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5 libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1 libkf5alarmcalendar5abi2 libkf5attica-dev libkf5auth-dev libkf5auth5 libkf5authcore5 libkf5baloo5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin
  libkf5baloowidgets-data libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bookmarks-dev libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarcore5abi2 libkf5calendarutils-bin libkf5calendarutils5abi1 libkf5cddb5 libkf5codecs-dev libkf5compactdisc5 libkf5completion-dev
  libkf5completion5 libkf5config-dev libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-dev libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5contacteditor5 libkf5contacts5 libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5crash5 libkf5dav5 libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5dbusaddons5
  libkf5declarative5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-dev libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5grantleetheme-plugins libkf5grantleetheme5 libkf5guiaddons-dev libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-dev
  libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5identitymanagement5abi1 libkf5idletime5 libkf5imap5 libkf5itemviews-dev libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-dev libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdcraw5
  libkf5kdegames7 libkf5kdegamesprivate7 libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml5 libkf5kio-dev libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiowidgets5
  libkf5kipi32.0.0 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5kmahjongglib5 libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5 libkf5ldap5abi1 libkf5libkdepim-plugins libkf5libkdepim5abi2 libkf5libkleo5abi1 libkf5mailtransport5abi2 libkf5mailtransportakonadi5 libkf5newstuff5
  libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications-dev libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5pimcommon-plugins libkf5pimcommon5abi3 libkf5pimcommonakonadi5
  libkf5pimtextedit5abi3 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5plotting5 libkf5prison5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5 libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5runner5 libkf5sane5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen7 libkf5service-bin
  libkf5service-dev libkf5service5 libkf5solid-dev libkf5solid5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5style5 libkf5su-bin libkf5su5 libkf5syntaxhighlighting5 libkf5texteditor-bin libkf5texteditor5 libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5torrent6abi1 libkf5wallet-bin
  libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5widgetsaddons-dev libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui-dev libkf5xmlgui5 libkfontinstui5 libkimageannotator0 libkpimgapicalendar5
  libkpimgapicontacts5 libkpimgapicore5abi1 libkpimgapitasks5 libkpimsmtp5abi1 libkpmcore11 libkscreenlocker5 libksysguardformatter1 libksysguardsensorfaces1 libksysguardsensors1 libkubuntu1 libkuserfeedbackcore1 libkuserfeedbackwidgets1
  libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwaylandserver5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects13 libkwinglutils13 libkwinxrenderutils13 libkworkspace5-5 liblayershellqtinterface5 libmanette-0.2-0 libmlt++3 libmlt6 libnotificationmanager1
  libokular5core9 liboxygenstyle5-5 liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libphonon4qt5-4 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libprocesscore9 libprocessui9 libqaccessibilityclient-qt5-0 libqapt3-runtime libqmobipocket2
  libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5hunspellinputmethod5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimediaquick5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5opengl5
  libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5printsupport5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quickparticles5 libqt5quickshapes5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libqt5quicktest5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5scripttools5 libqt5svg5 libqt5virtualkeyboard5
  libqt5waylandclient5 libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5x11extras5-dev libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-plasma
  libreoffice-qt5 libtaskmanager6 libweather-ion7 melt milou mozc-utils-gui multimc muon obs-studio okular okular-extra-backends partitionmanager pavucontrol-qt phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer pinentry-qt
  plasma-browser-integration plasma-calendar-addons plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-fwupd plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-disks plasma-firewall plasma-framework plasma-integration
  plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-systemmonitor plasma-thunderbolt plasma-vault plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace plasma-workspace-wayland polkit-kde-agent-1 polychromatic polychromatic-controller
  powerdevil print-manager python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer qhelpgenerator-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-activities qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop
  qml-module-org-kde-kaccounts qml-module-org-kde-kcm qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
  qml-module-org-kde-ksysguard qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-org-kde-prison qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle qml-module-org-kde-quickcharts
  qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-org-kde-userfeedback qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-particles2 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
  qml-module-qtwebengine qml-module-qtwebkit qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qt5-assistant qt5-default qt5-gtk-platformtheme qt5-image-formats-plugins qt5-qmltooling-plugins qt5-style-kvantum qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev
  qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtmultimedia5-dev qtscript5-dev qtspeech5-flite-plugin qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin qtwayland5 sddm sddm-theme-breeze signon-kwallet-extension signon-ui-x11 skanlite
  software-properties-qt systemsettings thermald ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt usb-creator-kde vlc vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2 xdg-desktop-portal-kde xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 435 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1 170 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I have no idea where to even start with this issue, do any of you?

Here's the output of `apt policy libevdev2` as requested by user535733:

```
libevdev2:
  Installed: 1.11.0+dfsg-1build1
  Candidate: 1.11.0+dfsg-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 1.11.0+dfsg-1build1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.9.0+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output of `sudo apt update` as requested by again user535733:

```
[sudo] password for ly: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/daily/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:5 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                   
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                            
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                      
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                       
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                   
Hit:7 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease                                        
Hit:14 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.40.1/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:15 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.5.1 ubuntu InRelease
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Sources [529 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2 207 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [746 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [385 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [275 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16,0 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [697 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [973 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [222 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [405 kB]                                                                                                                                                 
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]                                                                                                                                                
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Sources [252 kB]                                                                                                                                                                  
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1 822 kB]                                                                                                                                                         
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [515 kB]                                                                                                                                                            
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [301 kB]                                                                                                                                                           
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40,7 kB]                                                                                                                                                   
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [743 kB]                                                                                                                                                       
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [567 kB]                                                                                                                                                        
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [137 kB]                                                                                                                                                       
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [93,1 kB]                                                                                                                                               
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]                                                                                                                                             
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7 996 B]                                                                                                                                                  
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30,5 kB]                                                                                                                                              
Fetched 11,3 MB in 10s (1 174 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Edit: Removed random backslash on line 6. 
Edit: Added extra information related to the issue requested by user535733. 
Edit: Fixed some weird grammar.
Edit: Added even more information related to the issue again requested by user535733. 
Edit: Added more information related to the issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140441/discussion-on-question-by-zenjirou-problem-installing-package-libevdev-dev).

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion ended up being that I have mixed versions of software on my system which are incompatible with each-other, and my only solution is to re-install. 
Thank you user535733 for helping me come to this conclusion.